# PHP compare two arrays for matched key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

Been awake for too many hours and having issues with this one for some reason...

I am trying to compare 2 arrays for matched key=>value pairs and output the matched results.

**Array 1:** `$from['modules']`

```
Array( [8] => Array ( [object_module_id] => 8 [object_module_type] =>
CallLog [object_module_name] => Call Log ) [6] => Array (
[object_module_id] => 6 [object_module_type] => Files
[object_module_name] => Saved Files ) [7] => Array (
[object_module_id] => 7 [object_module_type] => Notes
[object_module_name] => Notes ))
```

**Array 2:** `$to[0]['modules']`

```
Array( [4] => Array ( [object_module_id] => 4 [object_module_type] =>
CallLog [object_module_name] => Call Log ) [2] => Array (
[object_module_id] => 2 [object_module_type] => Files
[object_module_name] => ) [10] => Array ( [object_module_id] => 10
[object_module_type] => Images [object_module_name] => ) [3] => Array
( [object_module_id] => 3 [object_module_type] => Notes
[object_module_name] => Notes ) [1] => Array ( [object_module_id] => 1
[object_module_type] => Passengers [object_module_name] => Passengers
))
```

I want to identify modules found in both arrays by both object_module_type && object_module_name and dump the matched results into `$module_matches[0]` as an array.

**Given the above arrays, I know that there should be 3 matches (by type & name)**

1. Array1->8 matches Array2->4
2. Array1->6 matches Array2->2
3. Array1->7 matches Array2->3

and I was hoping to get each matches details into an array something like the list above.

**EX:**

```
Array( [1] = >Array( ['from'] => ([object_module_id] => 8
[object_module_type] => CallLog [object_module_name] => Call
Log) ['to'] => ([object_module_id] => 4 [object_module_type] => CallLog
[object_module_name] => Call Log)) [2] => (...) [3] => (...))
```

My current attempt: dump results to `$module_matches[0]`

```
$module_matches[0] = array_intersect($to[0]['modules'], $from['modules']);
```

But the problem is `$module_matches[0]` just ends up being whatever array was entered into `array_intersect()` first? In this case `$module_matches[0]` returns Array2.

Comment: @whoami What array was clear? Very vague...

Comment: use `foreach`, it due to that array doesn't have same keys, it also uses `in_array`, `array_values`, `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try..

```
$matching_results = array();

foreach($from['modules'] as $from_id => $from_module){
    // Parse through each of the $from modules.
    $matches = 0;
    foreach($to[0]['modules'] as $to_id => $to_module){
        // Now we'll compare it to the $to modules...
        foreach($from_module as $from_key => $from_value){
            // So we'll break each $from module apart by key and val...
            if($to_module[$from_key] == $from_module[$from_key] && $from_key != 'object_module_id'){
                // If the array key isn't the ID, and if it matches
                // we'll increase our match counter by 1
                $matches++;
            }
        }
        if($matches == (count($from_module) - 1)){
            // the number of fields that need to match is
            // the total # of fields, minus the ID...
            $matching_results[$from_id] = $from_module;
        }
    }

}

var_dump($matching_results);
```